# Linq - difference with previous element

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a way to group data elements based on the difference between them?

```
List<Message> messages = new List<Message>(); 

class Message
{
    private DateTime Date { get; set; }
    private string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Example data in messages date:

```
14.3 2014 20:28:15
14.3 2014 20:32:17
14.3 2014 20:37:25
14.3 2014 22:38:43
14.3 2014 20:40:23
14.3 2014 20:42:07
14.3 2014 20:43:54
14.3 2014 20:52:26
14.3 2014 20:53:41
14.3 2014 20:55:37
14.3 2014 20:58:44
```

I need a `LINQ` query that group like this. If no record *six minutes*, will start a new group.

```
Group 1
    14.3 2014 20:28:15
    14.3 2014 20:32:17

Group 2
    14.3 2014 20:37:25
    14.3 2014 20:38:43
    14.3 2014 20:40:23
    14.3 2014 20:42:07
    14.3 2014 20:43:54

Group 3
    14.3 2014 20:52:26
    14.3 2014 20:53:41
    14.3 2014 20:55:37
    14.3 2014 20:58:44
```

Comment: It's really difficult to write a demonstrative linq query without knowing your class names, property names, etc. Can you post the actual class information, and show what you've tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: I edit question. I appreciate your interest, thanks you

Comment: @Lenny There is less then 6 minutes between `20:32:17` and `20:37:25`. Why aren't they both in the same group?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, we can create our own `GroupWhile` method, which lets us group items while a condition is met:

```
var query = messages.GroupWhile((prev, current) => 
    prev.Date.AddMinutes(6) >= current.Date));
```

`GroupWhile` can be implemented like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }

            list.Add(iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: It follows description from question, but produces different results (just 2 groups). Probably because text description and expected output set by OP do not match each other...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using only native Linq methods, you'd have to keep a sort of state variable outside of your linq query. It isn't good practice, but this would work:

```
var groupNum = 0;
var prevDate = DateTime.MinValue;
var threshold = -TimeSpan.FromMinutes(6); // negative time makes things easier

var groups = messages.GroupBy(
    m => prevDate - (prevDate = m.Date) < threshold ? ++groupNum : groupNum);
```

Again, keeping track of state variables outside a Linq query isn't really recommended, and this kind of code is horribly ugly and confusing. But it works.

I'd probably go with something more like [*Servy's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22416014/1715579) in a production environment.